# How can I call __missing__ from dict

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to derive from dict and overwrite the method missing. I would like to do some stuff and then still call its super function. Something like this:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        print('missing {}'.format(key))
        return super().__missing__(key)
```

Which however produces:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__missing__'
```

Of course I could still make a working program using:

```
raise KeyError(key)
```

But I would much rather call the super function. Because code could (or maybe at a future version of python will be) executed in `super().__missing__` other than raising the KeyError.

Comment: There's no `dict.__missing__` method; if you supply a `__missing__` for your dict subclass, you're supposed to return a value or raise an error on your own instead of trying to delegate it back to `dict`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `dict.__missing__`; just drop the call to `super().__missing__` (and raise a `KeyError`). The method is *optional* and has no default implementation.

Alternatively, if you want to support multiple inheritance properly, you could catch the `AttributeError` exception:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        print('missing {}'.format(key))
        try:
            return super().__missing__(key)
        except AttributeError:
            raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: Dropping the super call on its own wouldn't be enough, since then you'd get `None` for all missing keys.

Comment: @user2357112: the idea being that you raise `KeyError` instead, I'll clarify.

Comment: Sorry Martin, wrong tree. I wish I also got a comment (or 2 now). The answer may not be spot on like yours, but imho it could also be an alternative for the OP. On Saturday someone had a 6 line rant against an answer of mine because it was selected as the answer and he also downvoted it ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess your right and this is just a language construct I have to live with. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @mementum: glad my suspicion was unfounded! :-) It happens, people get rather too attached to their points sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

subclass from `collections.defaultdict` which already features a **missing** method.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

> ## `__missing__`(*key*)
>
> **If the `default_factory` attribute is `None`, this raises a `KeyError` exception with the *key* as argument.**
>
> If default_factory is not `None`, it is called without arguments to
>   provide a default value for the given *key*, this value is inserted in
>   the dictionary for the *key*, and returned.
>
> If calling `default_factory` raises an exception this exception is
>   propagated unchanged.
>
> This method is called by the `__getitem__()` method of the dict class
>   when the requested *key* is not found; whatever it returns or raises is
>   then returned or raised by `__getitem__()`.
>
> Note that `__missing__()` is *not* called for any operations besides
>   `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using `default_factory`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I would actually much rather subclass from `dict`.

Comment: Always your choice, just wanted to offer an alternative