# How to make dict element value as list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list. Let's say `[3,4,2,3,4,2,1,4,5]`.

I need to create a dictionary from the indexes of the elements.

Here in this case, I need to create a dict as follows:

```
{
   '3':[0,3],
   '4':[1,4,7],
   '2':[2,5],
   '1':[6],
   '5':[8]
}
```

where the element values are the indexes of the keys in list provided.

I've tried. But was able to change the values as integers only. But unable to make them as list.

Is there any way to do this with just 1 for loop?

The code I've tried:

```
d=dict()
ll=[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,5,4,2,4,6,5,6,78,3,2,4,5,7,8,9,4,4,2,2,34,5,6,3]
for i,j in enumerate(ll):
    d[j].append(i)
print(d)
```

Comment: Yes there is a way using only one loop. What have you tried?

Comment: @Sukumar edit it into your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: Ah, that would work if the default value for a dictionary entry was an empty list. See @jpp's solution.

Comment: Should the keys really be `str`, or `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `set`:

```
d = [3,4,2,3,4,2,1,4,5]
new_d = {i:[c for c, a in enumerate(d) if i == a] for i in set(d)}
```

Output:

```
{1: [6], 2: [2, 5], 3: [0, 3], 4: [1, 4, 7], 5: [8]}
```

Comment: Nice one-liner, but even with a `set` this is O(n²).

Comment: @Ajax1234 Your solution one looks awesome :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for an O(n) solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

A = [3,4,2,3,4,2,1,4,5]

for idx, val in enumerate(A):
    d[val].append(idx)

print(d)

defaultdict(list, {1: [6], 2: [2, 5], 3: [0, 3], 4: [1, 4, 7], 5: [8]})
```

Comment: I've come across this solution. But I'm wondering if there is any way to do that without importing anything.

Comment: @Sukumar What is the problem with importing anything?

Comment: Yes, was looking for `setdefault` there, too early in the morning :P

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5]
d = {}
for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
    d.setdefault(item, []).append(index)
```

results in

```
{3: [0, 3], 4: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5], 1: [6], 5: [8]}
```

Why? Well, we iterate over the list, and for each item, we first make sure that there is a list in the dictionary mapped to by this item. Then we append the respective index to that list. What results is a dictionary which maps each seen item to a list of indexes it was found at.

The solution is similar to jpp's solution, except of the part with `.setdefault()`, which creates an empty list in every loop run, while the `defaultdict` approach only creates new lists if needed.

Another approach could be a `dict` subclass which implements [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/2.5.html?highlight=__missing__#other-language-changes). This is called whenever a key isn't present.

```
class ListDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        l = []
        self[key] = l
        return l
```

and then just do `d[item].append(index)`. Now, whenever a key is not found, `__missing__()` is called which "fixes" the problem. See also [How can I call __missing__ from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34884402/296974) for this.

Answer (score 2):

This will work, the key thing you're looking for is the enumerate() function:

```
list_to_convert = [3,4,2,3,4,2,1,4,5]
out_dict = {}

for idx, val in enumerate(list_to_convert):
    if val in out_dict:
        out_dict[val].append(idx)
    else:
        out_dict[val] = [idx,]

print (out_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{3: [0, 3], 4: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5], 1: [6], 5: [8]}
```